# UWP: webview making my app run front on startup among other apps

Tags: webview, uwp, focus

i have changed settings for my pc for my startup folder it works in background but i want to show it in front i would like to know how can i achieve this

```
<Page
    x:Class="UWS_FOREGROUND.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UWS_FOREGROUND"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <!-- Source file is on the web. -->
    <WebView DefaultBackgroundColor="Black" x:Name="webView1" Source="someUrl" />

</Page>
```

Comment: Hello, i dont understand what you mean, could you explain a bit more what you wish to do? your link is working and the webview is loading the content for me.

Comment: HI @Damien my code works but i want my app should start automatically so for that i created a shortcut icon and kept in this C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup so its started automatically but the problem there is another windows app installed in my pc due to that my app run in background but i want my app to run show on top

Comment: You could add a screenshot to help clear your issue. For "there is another windows app installed ", did this app also start automatically? For "due to that my app run in background", did you mean your app is show behind of that app?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT yes you are exactly right : that app also starts automatically and yes my app is behind this app but not like screen by screen but i can see only my app if i use ctrl + tab